# Which exception should be raised on unknown keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

In Python, which exception should be raised when an unknown keyword argument is passed to the function?  Should it be [`SyntaxError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError)? I saw that Python itself raises [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#TypeError), but I am not sure why.

For example:

```
def add(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.pop('a', 0.)
    b = kwargs.pop('b', 0.)

    if kwargs:
        # what to raise here?
        raise SyntaxError('Unknown keyword arguments: ' + list(kwargs.keys()))
        # or ? 
        # raise TypeError('Unknown keyword arguments: ' + list(kwargs.keys()))

    return a + b
```

Comment: Why don't you define ``def add(a=0., b=0.):`` instead of manually emulating this?

Comment: `SyntaxError` would be confusing in my opinion - that has to do with parsing, not an incorrect parameter.

Comment: It *definitely should not be a syntax error* because it isn't a syntax error. `SyntaxErrors`  So use `TypeError`. IOW, that code would *compile fine*, there is nothing wrong with the syntax, like, say assigning to a keyword, e.g. `for = 42`

Comment: Keyword arguments are (arguably) part of the function's type. Its the normal way to handle the error so its the most expected.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This is a MWE.  In the real case I need to keep it as `**kwargs` as `add` is an overriden method of a sub-class.  The base class allows defining `add` with any number / combination of arguments.

Comment: Please clarify what your question is. Are you wondering which exception must be raised to emulate Python's default behaviour? Are you wondering why Python raises ``TypeError`` instead of ``SyntaxError``? Are you wondering why Python raises ``TypeError`` instead of *some other* error, e.g. also ``ValueError``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would like to know what is the standard (or most common) exception that I need to raise in this case.  (In particular that would emulate Python's default behavior, if there is a standard.)

Comment: @kMaster I don't understand the reasoning for using ``**kwargs``. If the function accepts ``**kwargs`` but raises an appropriate error on unexpected arguments, the behaviour is practically indistinguishable from only accepting the expected arguments. Doing this manually doesn't make the signature mismatch any more or less correct.

Comment: @kMaster Your question notes that you already know Python raises ``TypeError``. What *else* do you need?

Comment: I understand that using `**kwargs` is useful (I do it too), but in this example, it seems like you don't need to. Its okay for a subclass method to have a different call signature than its parent. That's what you are doing by enforcing `if kwargs:` - you are enforcing a different call signature than the parent. Your example is equivalent to `def add(a=0., b=0.)` and in that case it should raise the same exception.

Comment: @tdelaney That's helpful to know.  I thought it is bad practice to have a method with different signature than the parent's method's.  At least `pylint` complains about signature of the overridden function being different than the main one.

Comment: its not a normal thing to do but here you are enforcing a specialization. You see something similar with say, sockets, that look like files but you can't seek. One may question the design of the parent method that takes everything but if its reasonable in your case, then you just have to ignore the pylint barking.

Comment: Thank you, @tdelaney!  In fact in this case I am implementing both the parent class and the child.  The parent's method actually did not require any arguments (would implement a default behavior).  The child was supposed to add some flexibility and required two arguments.  To be nice to `pylint` I ended up adding `**kwargs` to both methods, and throwing a `TypeError`s in both to enforce the exact number of arguments I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The appropriate error for unexpected or missing arguments is `TypeError`.

```
>>> def add(a, b=0.): ...
>>> add(a=3, c=5)
TypeError: add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
>>> add(1, 2, 3)
TypeError: add() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
>>> add()
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

---

While the concrete type of a function is just `function`, Python semantically uses the common [function type model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_type) in which the type of a function is its signature, i.e. `Parameters -> Result`. For example, the function

```
def add(a, b): return a + b
```

has the type `(a: Any, b: Any) -> Any`. As far as types are concerned, it is exchangeable with any other function of the same signature. This is codified by Python's optional [static type support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) as well.

Calling a function means supplying matching `Parameters`. This uses Python's rules for matching arguments to parameters, e.g. `add(b=3, a=1)` still matches `add(a: Any, b: Any)`.

A call with incompatible signature, e.g. `add(1, 2, 3)`, means a function of *different* type is expected at the call site, e.g. `(:Any, :Any, :Any) -> Any` in this case. This means the type/signature of the call and the function do not match. Thus, `TypeError` is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It'd probably be most appropriate to do the same as what Python itself does, which is that it raises a `TypeError` exception:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...   pass
...
>>> f(a=1, b=2, c=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'
```

A `TypeError` is also raised if you give more positional arguments than what the function supports, which also indicates that `TypeError` describes this kind of error the best (and is what you'd expect from Python itself).

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.